# How to conditionally SELECT multiple columns with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, select, prepared-statement, control-flow, prepare

Suppose I have 3 columns to choose from: `colA`, `colB` and `colC`.

We have 7 possibilities to SELECT from:

```
single column: colA | colB | colC
double column: colA colB  | colA colC | colB colC
triple column: colA colB colC
```

---

I would like to make a query that enables me to pick which columns I want to SELECT. For instance, if I want to pick columns `colB` and `colC`, then the SELECT should return

```
colB colC
---------
 1    4
 2    5
 3    6
---------
```

---

I already searched for quite some time, and what I encounter most are the `CASE` and `IF` [Control Flow Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html), but I could not achieve what it's described with them. For example, if I make the following query, the columns that are not activated show up with NULL values (whereas they should not show up):

```
SET @colB_switch := 1;
SET @colC_switch := 0;

SELECT
    CASE WHEN @colB_switch = 1 THEN colB END,
    CASE WHEN @colC_switch = 1 THEN colC END
FROM my_table
```

---

For this simple case, I could simple hard code every single possibility, but when we have dozens of columns we have literally thousands of possibilities!

PS: another approach would be pick which columns to *not* show up, maybe it's easier?

Comment: you may have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/if-statement.html

Comment: A SQL query has a fixed set of columns.  If you want a variable set of columns, you need to use a `prepare` statement (aka dynamic SQL).

Comment: @GordonLinoff Hey. Would it be something along these lines: `SET @stat := CONCAT('SELECT ', @colA, @colB, @colC, ' FROM my_table');`
`PREPARE stmt1 FROM @stat;`
`EXECUTE stmt1;` ? This works if I take care of commas in the placeholders for the columns. Tomorrow I'll try to implement it in the client side (VBA - ADODB).

Comment: @feelthhis . . . Something like that.  It is easier with `concat_ws()`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Maybe `CONCAT('SELECT ', CONCAT_WS(',', @colA, @colB, @colC), ' FROM my_table')` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @GordonLinoff [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25577017/how-to-conditionally-select-multiple-columns-with-mysql?noredirect=1#comment39947054_25577017), here's one way to conditionally SELECT multiple columns with MySQL:

```
SET @colA := NULL;
SET @colB := 'colB';
SET @colC := 'colC';

SET @stat := CONCAT('SELECT ', CONCAT_WS(',', @colA, @colB, @colC), ' FROM my_table');

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @stat;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

[CONCAT_WS()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) is convenient because if I do not want to SELECT a given column, I just set it to `NULL` (colA, in the example).

Comment: Nice solution. I like it.

Comment: @estshy I'm glad that you liked it! :)